# Best way to stream command line output to a webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, command-line

Hi I've got an app that runs a long running process on the command line.

Is there a recommended or good way to stream the output messages asynchonously to a web form so there's some indication of progress? A bit like TeamCity does for build scripts.

Should I be polling a webservice? Using the [OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event? Turning off buffering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on what you need the UI to look like.  If it's just a utility-type thing, I'd just turn off response buffering.

However, if you need it to look pretty, use AJAX to poll a web service.

Answer (score 0):

I feel its better using a service which can be remoted. The commandline app's output should go to the remoted service, and should be available in its memory. The webservice should call a remoted method which can read this output (stored in the remoting service's memory).